# Can not install Poly base on SQL Server 2017 (With failover cluster Instance)

Tags: sql-server, polybase

The version of my SQL Server is 2017 and it's a failover cluster (with two nodes)
I followed the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-installation?view=sql-server-ver15

I installed Poly-base on exiting SQL Server instance and chose standalone instance and finally I got an error message

[image]

> Install of feature SQL_PolyBase_Core_Inst is not supported on clustered instance

So my question is: Is it a limitation on SQL Server 2017 or I missed something?

Comment: Before you install PolyBase on your SQL Server instances, decide whether you want a single node installation or a PolyBase scale-out group. ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-installation?view=sql-server-ver15#single-node-or-polybase-scale-out-group)) I think you should use Polybase scale-out groups.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't installed in in a FCI but this links shows it works: https://sqlserverbang.blogspot.com/2020/07/sql-server-polybase-in-failover-cluster.html

Comment: Perhaps the SQL server version of yours is 2019, so it woks?

Answer (score 0):

As per pre requisites:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-installation?view=sql-server-ver15#prerequisites

> You cannot add features to a failover cluster instance after creation.
> For example, you cannot add the PolyBase feature to an existing
> failover cluster instance.